# How do I serve dynamic WebDAV directory listings using Apache

Tags: apache, dynamic

I can use mod_rewrite to redirect `/dynamic.php/xyz.php` to `/dynamic.php` and then server different content for xyz.php using `$_SERVER` - where `xyz.php` is any arbitrary filename requested by a client. No problem so far.

When a client connects to my WebDAV server they can list the contents of a directory, eg `/` or `/dynamic.php/` - how do I intercept this request so I can dynamically generate a list of available files for the client (which requests this list using `PROPFIND`)?

Comment: This question should be migrated to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Does your client accesses page through a browser? If so, in every directory you can put a PHP file which would show a list of files as per your rules.

**Another approach**

You can redirect user to a specific PHP file where you can show lists as per your rules by comparing referral URL.

Comment: no, "a client connects to my WebDAV server" using a WebDAV client - in this case dav2fs